# Error in converting string to json object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

```
a = "{'sentiments': [['1485925200000', '0.0636363636364']]}"
// typeof(a) returns string
```

Trying to convert this string to json object in angular using JSON.parse(a). However, I am getting an error.

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'`

Comment: `JSON.parse( a.replace(/'/g, '"') )`!

Comment: @E.Sundin Before the word sentiments ?

Comment: Every instance of `'`, like so ````a = `{"sentiments": [["1485925200000", "0.0636363636364"]]}````

Comment: you mean... convert string to json string? javascript object? how are you getting this... string? it isn't valid json and therefore cannot be parsed as json.

Comment: @KevinB the source is a RestAPI from python. The answer mentioned below worked.

Comment: then the restapi is broken. it should be fixed, rather than using regex to parse invalid json. Invalid json in this format suggests a json string being built by hand, which is also a pretty serious problem.

Comment: Well I cant change the API. But what I **can** do is handle the problem in javascript. Which is what this questions was for

Comment: Someone can change the api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have `'` which are not supported by the ***JSON*** format, you can do something like:

```
a = "{'sentiments': [['1485925200000', '0.0636363636364']]}"
JSON.parse(a.replace(/'/g,'"'))
```

This uses regular expressions to find all instances of `'` and replace them with `"`. So that your JSON can be parsed.

#### Edit

A more dangerous, yet acceptable approach could also be used in this example by using `eval()` since `'` is considered a valid string declarator in JavaScript, thus you could do:

```
const myObject = eval(a)
```

Comment: i mean... it's correct, until the string contains a string that contains single quotes. the... *correct*... way to fix this would be to fix the source, not run a regex on a string that should be json.

Comment: Addressed your use case @KevinB

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Comment: `/\'/g` could be just `/'/g` no need to escape it!

Answer (score 3):

Since my comment was poorly formatted I'm providing an answer.

Change your JSON format to the following valid one, replacing all `'` with `"`.

`` a = `{"sentiments": [["1485925200000", "0.0636363636364"]]}` ``